# Проблема в вычислении площади треугольника

Tags: c++, математика

Нужно составить программу вычисления n Героновых треугольников где длины сторон последовательные целые числа и площадь тоже,проблема с вычислением площади треугольника такая:мне нужно чтобы для каждого треугольника вычислялась площадь,то есть,например:я ввожу n треугольников и на выводе я желаю получить:

```
a=0 b=0 c=0 s=0
......
a=3 b=4 c=5 s=6
```

а у меня а, b, c как бы накапливают значения и s тоже при вводе 5 например:
a=6 b=12 c=18 s=-2147483648

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int n;
int a,b,c,p= 0;
int s = 0;
int main() 
{   cout << "Vvedite n:";
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i += 1, a += 1, b += 2, c += 3)
        p = (a + b + c) / 2;
        s = p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c);
        s = sqrt(s);
    cout << "a=" << a << " b=" << b << " c=" << c << " s=" << s << endl;
}
```

Comment: Забыли фигурные скобки после `for`?

Comment: спасибо,но тогда следующий вопрос,почему у меня площадь 0 для каждого треугольника при вводе 5?

Comment: Если посмотрите значения переменных в дебаггере, то увидите бы, что на каждой итерации получается `p == c`, так что происходит умножение на 0 в `* (p - c)`. Может формула вычисления площади неправильная?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то меня терзают смутные сомнения, что у вас все треугольники будут вырожденные - нулевой площади.

Вот пример для [почти равносторонних Героновых треугольников](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA#%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B8_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8) (можно и другими заняться, но это, пожалуй, самый простой вариант):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0, j = 4, last = 2; i < n; ++i, j = j*4 - last, last = (j+last)/4)
    {
        int a = j-1, b = j, c = j+1;
        double s = (a+b+c)/2.0;
        s = sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c));
        cout << "a = " << a << ", b = " << b << ", c = "
            << c << ":  s = " << s << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: for(int i = 0, j = 4, last = 2; i < n; ++i, j = j*4 - last, last = (j+last)/4) объясните исходя из этой строки что вы тут делаете?

Comment: По ссылке указано, как считать три последовательных числа, которые образуют геронов треугольник - надо предыдущее умножить на 4 и вычесть прерпредыдущее. j у меня это текущее значение, которое для следующего числа становится предыдущим - вот мы его и вычисляем `j = j*4 - last`, переменная `last` - это предпредыдущее... Сохраняем его: `last = (j+last)/4` . Для первой тройки 3,4,5 `last` равно 2.